# Assigning Values to a Nested Dictionary Error

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nested

I have data coming in that contains a Timestamp, and Open, High, Low, and Close values.

I'm trying to organize it in a dictionary so that at each timestamp, there is a key holding the corresponding Open, High, Low and Close values.

What I've done so far:

I started by initialing an empty dictionary called `newest_bar`.

Then, every time a new bar is added, I first set a new key called `'Timestamp'` that will contain the time for that new bar. Then from there I'm running a `for` loop, to nest the corresponding Open, High, Low and close values under that Timestamp.

Here's my attempt:

```
def append(self, bar):
    key = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']
    values = [bar.Open, bar.High, bar.Low, bar.Close]
    self.newest_bar['TimeStamp'] = bar.Timestamp
    for i, item in enumerate(key):
        self.newest_bar['TimeStamp'][item] = values[i]

    print(self.newest_bar)
```

However I keep getting this error which is telling me that I'm prob not doing the key assignment correctly.

> TypeError: 'pywintypes.datetime' object does not support item assignment

An example of the data:

```
Timestamp: 2019-07-17 10:58:00+00:00
Open: 1.8877
High: 1.8878
Low: 1.8871
Close: 1.8878
```

Example of the output

```
{'TimeStamp': '2019-07-17 10:58:00+00:00' 
        {'Open":1.8877, 'High':1.8878, 'Low':1.8871, 'Close':1.8878}
```

Comment: If possible, show how you want `newest_bar` to look like. By that I mean, show an example data of the variable `newest_bar`. You need to visualize how your data should look like, then design the code based on that to make the required data structure.

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami Done

Comment: I have no idea what that output is supposed to mean. How do you intend to assign a dictionary and a timestamp to the same key? Do you mean to just have a flat dictionary?

Comment: I'm trying to have a nested dictionary so that every time stamp contains 4 keys with the open, high, low and close values so that if i want to reference the open of the 2019-07-17 10:55 bar I can do it @MadPhysicist

Comment: Then you have it backwards. The timestamp itself should be the key, not the word 'Timestamp'. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the names, like `append` and `newest_bar`, you are trying to place bar information into a dictionary keyed by timestamp. There is no reason for having a key called `Timestamp`: access to the bar information is provided by the timestamp itself. As such, you will probably want to maintain a dictionary, let's call it `bars` in `self`. The only place that you might want to have the timestamp information for convenience is in `self.newest_bar`, to let users know when your last update happened. A such, there is no harm in including `Timestamp` in the keys for each bar:

```
bar_keys = ['Timestamp', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Cloe']

...

def append(self, bar):
    self.newest_bar = {key: getattr(bar, key) for key in bar_keys}
    self.bars[self.newest_bar['Timestamp']] = self.newest_bar
```

You can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) and a [comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) to make a dictionary in one step, rather than unpacking to a list and then repacking with a loop. I also suggest extracting the list of keys to the class body, since otherwise it will make a new list every time you call the function.

Comment: So im a little confused. You are correct that Im essentially just trying to add any newest bar information to my dictionary. I have a newest_bar in self. Im not sure why you want me to add another dictionary called bars?

Comment: I've done that and added bars to self. but I still get this error:     self.bars[newest_bar['Timestamp']] = self.newest_bar
NameError: name 'newest_bar' is not defined. I have the bar_keys=key line of code in the append function. Will that cause an issue?

Comment: @novawaly. Adding `bar_keys` back into your function shouldn't be a problem. I assumed that you wanted to have `newest_bar`  point to just the single latest bar, while `bars` is a mapping of all the times you've processed to their corresponding bar data. `newest_bar` gets overwritten every time you call `append` in both our codes.

Comment: do i need a self. infront of newest_bar['Timestamp']?

Comment: Ah ok. I see what you're trying to do. so in that last line of code, wouldn't I need to give it the actual timestamp somewhere instead of the word TimeStamp?

Comment: Yes, you're right and I fixed my code. `self.newest_bar['Timestamp']` *is* the actual timestamp. `[...]` performs the lookup

Comment: ah ok - the timestamp is in bar.Timestamp. So if i just change the last line of code to this, it should work right?    self.bars[bar.Timestamp] = self.newest_bar

Comment: also just for my own edification - i've never seen the bar_keys = keys = [] before. What exactly is that doing?

Comment: @novawaly `bar_keys = keys = []` is a chained assignment, and a typo on my part :). It's technically valid, in the sense that it assigns the same list reference to both variables, but it's just an artifact of sloppy editing on my part.